# Is it possible to develop games on Linux with the Unity game engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

A few months back I was using the Unity game engine to build some games on Windows. Later I had to switch to Linux Mint (due to some reasons). Is it possible to still use Unity on Linux. If not are there any alternatives for Unity where I can build games on Linux?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this may be better suited for [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design)

Comment: I don't think this is on topic for this site. However, just a FYI, I did see that they did a [experimental build](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/) of 5.1.0f3. I don't know if that build was maintained. You could also switch to [Unreal Engine](http://www.unrealengine.com) they have a dedicated linux dev environment.

Comment: thanks for informing me @wondercricket i'll repost it there now

Comment: @NEO I would check with the regulation on the site first to ensure it is on topic there as well

Comment: There is no need to post this again. Unity supports Linux but this is still in experimental mode because Linux support was added just few years ago. It works 100 percent. You can see what's going on and get the latest version [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/).

Comment: @Programmer okay i'll try installing it on linux

Answer (score 3):

2019-04 update: the Linux editor has been upgraded from Experimental to Preview: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/04/16/introducing-unity-2019-1/#linuxeditor The blog post links to downloads at: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v-1-6-0-is-now-available.640792/

2018-01 original answer: The Unity devs are linking to Linux downloads as the last post of this "only devs can post" thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/

I have then downloaded the latest available release 2017.3.0p2 and it launched correctly on Ubuntu 17.10. It is of course lagging behind the main release for a year, but at least it seemed to work.

My lack of Unity knowledge does not allow me to say that there is wide feature support however.

I encourage you to go and upvote that thread and give it a shot to show devs that the Linux community is interested.

Also mentioned on this question: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1265472/where-to-download-latest-unity3d-editor-for-linux.html

As for the alternatives, I also compiled Unreal Release tag 4.18.3-release from source and it just worked, so clearly Unreal is much ahead in terms of Linux support.

Answer (score 2):

***You can use Unity on Linux but without any future guarantee***. At this time its Linux unity Build is on experimental basis as NA'TOSHA BARD mentioned in his blog on 26 Aug 2015.

> Today’s build is what we call an experimental build; **future support is
>   not yet guaranteed**.  Your adoption and feedback will help us determine
>   if this is something we can sustain alongside our Mac and Windows
>   builds([**ref**](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/))

So it up to you to use experimental build, remember i didn't find any latest post on Linux Unity build after the above mentioned date([**ref**](https://unity3d.com/search?gq=linux)).